# Rails: passing large amounts of data between controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller with three actions: `index`, `iframe`, and `result`.  The way it works is the user visits the `index` action via GET request.  This renders a view that includes a form.  The form is simply a button that POSTs to `result`.  My `result` action simply renders a page that includes a jQuery progress bar and an iframe, the content of which is the `iframe` action.  The `iframe` action does some long-running processing and eventually returns the result to the `result` view.  (The whole reason I need to do this in an iframe is so the `result` action returns quickly with a progress bar so the user doesn't think the application crashed.)

Previously the form consisted solely of a button that POSTed to `result`.  In this scenario, the `iframe` action downloads a ~100MB file from a static URL and does some processing on it, then updates the parent page (`result`) with the result of the processing.

Now I need to provide the option of uploading a file to process instead of always using the static URL to download from.  Basically, if a user provides a file, use that file; otherwise, use the static URL.  I have modified my form to accept a file upload and this part is working fine.  My problem is how to pass this uploaded file, which is ~100MB, from `result` to `iframe`.  It is far too big to put in the session.  The uploaded file does not need to be saved between runs.

Comment: Are you doing the processing server side or client side?

Comment: Server side.  I figured out a (temporary) solution, which was to save the uploaded file to a new File, then pass the location of the newly created file to my iframe via `session[:something] = "/tmp/my_new_file.zip"`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the implementation detail, you should update your question with a bit more of the background of the problem - what kind of files are you uploading? What kind of processing do you do? What is the purpose of the system from an end-users perspective? It'll help people understand the problem you're trying to solve.

I'm making some assumptions about the purpose of your system here, but here's what I'd do:

I'd upload files and store them in the file system, and also create a new record in a database table indicating the location of the file within the system, and wether the file is "processed" or not. You can use the Carrier Wave gem for this: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

I'd then use some kind of background job tool to do the actual processing. So, when a file is uploaded, you add it to the 'queue of stuff to be processed', then return a message to the user saying "the job has been added to the queue for processing and will be finished soon". The ID of the row you saved in the database table can serve as the identifier for which file needs to be processed. Once it's processed, you update the "processed" column in the database to be `true`. There are several gems to choose from when it comes to background jobs - one popular one is SideKiq - http://sidekiq.org/

At that point, it's basically up to you in terms of how smooth you want to make the process from your end user's perspective. A simplest case would be:

When you return the message "the job has been added to the queue for processing and will be finished soon," you could also say "It should be complete within a few mintues. Refresh this page to see if your job is complete". Each refresh, if the processing is complete, you'd let them know.

A more sophisticated way would be: Once the "job has been added to the queue" page is shown, you could display a timer counting how long it's been, and use a javascript timer to regularly make AJAX requests to the server every couple of seconds to check if the job has been completed. Once the job has been completed, update the page to indicate that, using AJAX.